# On the zeros of the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Let us consider the infinite set of non-trivial zeros of **Riemann zeta function** $\{\rho_n \}$ and the following product

$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\rho_n}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\overline{\rho}_n}\bigg)=1.
$$

We trivially note that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\rho_n}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\overline{\rho}_n}\bigg) = \bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\rho_n}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\overline{\rho}_n}\bigg)
$$

if and only if $\Re(\rho_n)=1/2$. Does this mean that

$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\rho_n}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\overline{\rho}_n}\bigg) = 1
$$

if and only if $\Re(\rho_n)=1/2$, and furthermore that $\zeta(1-z)=0$ if and only if $\Re(z)=1/2$ ?

Comment: By the functional equation if $\rho$ is a zero we have $1-\rho$ a zero too so the zeroes group in fours if not on the critical line and in twos if on the critical line

Comment: @Conrad But what is your opinion? Surely it would be funny to find a trivial way to deduce $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-[2\Re(\rho_n)-1]/ |\rho_n|^2)=1$ iff $\Re(\rho_n)=1/2$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; there are a ton of functions with a similar root decomposition (same symmetries) and with the value at $1$ as above for which the roots can be anything you want as long as you group them in four outside the critical line, so it is not true that any relation as above implies anything else about the zeroes

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-\frac1s)(1-\frac1{1-s}) = \frac{s-1}{s}\frac{-s}{1-s}=1$$
no need that $\Re(s)=1/2$